# Manually edit boltdb file

Tags: database, go, boltdb

I have an app written on **golang** and I want to create a **builin database**, I've selected **boltdb**. *I have some init data that I want to seed into database manually*. I have **database.db** file and I want to put some data into it.

When I open this file - **I see many 'NUL' words**. How can I edit .db file manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't edit it manually, you have to write code code that'd do that for you.

Comment: I agree that you should generally write code to manage your database state. However, if you need to inspect the database or tweak a value for some reason, Brian Buller's boltbrowser is a nice termbox UI for Bolt:


https://github.com/br0xen/boltbrowser

Comment: Another one for inspect the db, check this [go install go.etcd.io/bbolt/cmd/bbolt@latest](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/tutorials/monitoring/inspect-data-boltdb#using-the-bbolt-cli). It will be installed in `/root/go/bin/bbolt` for root user.